# Django DRF - Auto Increment Field set Start value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django DRF and looking for a solution to set start value for auto increment field in the model. The default value starts from 1. I want to set the start value as a 5 digit number. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I would think you could do something like this by setting your own primary key on the database. Define an additional field on your model like so:

```
my_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, min_value=10000)
```